# how to load views into an MVC application when using angular

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a project in which I am loading a view which contains an angular app. Within the angular app I have templates that I am trying to load. 
Within VS the directory structure shows

```
/views/reports/library.cshtml
```

within this directory I have added an html file/template

```
/views/reports/modal1.html
```

When I try to reference this html file either through angular or just through the address bar `http://localhost/reports/modal1.html or http://localhost/views/reports/modal1.html`I get a 404 error. It appears that angular is looking to the root of the website but I suspect the asp.net MVC routing is overriding something. I'd like to keep the files together for the app within the "view" directory vs. dumping them in the root. How do I go about loading the html templates within an MVC solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a .webconfig in the views folder which prevents loading static files. Normally, you would not put the angular views in the mvc views. I would create a separate app directory at the root of the project:

```
/app
    /scripts
        /controllers
        /services
    /views
```

Another option is to allow for static files in the web.config in the views folder

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="HtmlScriptHandler" path="*.html" verb="*"
     preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
    <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
    <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
  </handlers>
```

Comment: the challenge I have is this is not a new project but a phased implementation where I am cutting in SPA's into a hybrid webform/MVC application. It's pretty large to where I would like to keep files together vs. introducing new directories.I'll try the static files approach this looks like it may be the approach to take for this solution.

Comment: I can't see a problem with adding another directory for the angular app inside your legacy application. Technically the Views folder is meant for mvc views and that is all

Comment: so you propose to create a new directory from the root and add the templates there for the MVC view?

Comment: I would normally create an app directory from the root which would be used for the angular app and everything for the app would be nested inside it. I updated my answer as the formatting wasn't the best